# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

1. Внимательно выслушав рассказ друга (,) Вадик понял, что речь идет о больших деньгах.
2. Как глава компании(,) он понимал, что необходимо предпринимать решительные действия.

Answer (score 1):

Вторая запятая нужна! Оборот с как имеет значение причины. (Он понимал, что нужны решительные действия потому, что он глава компании.)

Answer (score 0):

Первая запятая однозначно нужна для выделения деепричастного оборота. Вторую запятую можно не ставить.